# @media don't work properly with polymer custom css

Tags: html, css, polymer

I have 2 inputs and I want to make font-size appear small on small screens and big on normal screens but when I use custom css(ie --paper-input-container-label) @media seems not to work properly, testing code below on small screens (height < 320) use css inside of min-height: 480px @media instead max-height: 320px

**HTML**

```
    <paper-input-container>
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input is="iron-input">
    </paper-input-container>

    <paper-input-container>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input is="iron-input" type="password">
    </paper-input-container>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen (max-height: 320px) {
    paper-input-container {
        --paper-input-container-label: {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        --paper-input-container-input: {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
}

@media only screen(min-height: 480px) {
    paper-input-container {
        --paper-input-container-label: {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        --paper-input-container-input: {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query ?

Comment: I tried that option but I could not make it work :( or I don't know how to use iron-media-query https://jsfiddle.net/c5mq2rbt/5/<--- this example in chrome I can see what is inside template in all resolutions and in firefox nothing shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `<iron-media-query>` inside an `<template is="dom-bind">` or inside a `<dom-module>` for it to be able to set a variable (`isBetween500_700px`)

```
  <body class="fullbleed">

    <template is="dom-bind">
      <iron-media-query query="(min-width:500px)" query-matches="{{isBetween500_700px}}"></iron-media-query>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{isBetween500_700px}}">
        <!-- anything in here is displayed only when the display port is between 500 and 700 pixels-->
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>I am inside 500x700 </p>

      </template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{!isBetween500_700px}}">
        <p>I am inside other</p>
      </template>
    </template>

  </body>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eoXnWuLRENnFlUrte6gr?p=preview)

For more details see also the source code of [`<iron-media-query>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) in the `/demo` directory which contains a nice example https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-media-query/blob/master/demo/index.html