# Applying CSS to Polymer custom element with iron-media-query

Tags: html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to achieve a simple 'media-query' behavior on my custom element using `<iron-media-query>` from the Polymer API.

Assume i have a container with some text on top the top, and below it is the main content..
My goal is to write media queries so that when the element is displayed on a big screen (just bigger than 768px for my testing), i can do some simple margin and padding modifications to the elements local DOM styles.

I just can't make it work. 
Is there something i completely missed here ?

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-media-query/iron-media-query.html" />
```

```
<iron-media-query query="(max-width:768px)" query-matches="{{isMobilePhone}}"></iron-media-query>

<template is="dom-if" if="{{isMobilePhone}}">

    <style>
        #title {
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 1.8em;
        }
    </style>


</template>


<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            background-color: gray;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            display: flex;
            width: 90%;
            flex-grow: 1;
            max-width: 1300px;
        }

        #title {
            color: #7DB8C9;
            font-size: 1.3em;
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>


    <p id="title">
        [[title]]
    </p>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <content select=".content"></content>
    </div>

</template>




<script>
    Polymer({

        is: 'content-container',
        properties: {
            title: String,
            isMobilePhone: Boolean
        },
        listeners: {
            'tap': 'spit'
        },
        spit: function() {
            console.log("BOOL: " + this.isMobilePhone);
        }

    });
</script> </dom-module>
```

I also tried copying the whole template ( with styles and markup ) inside the 'if' template and just modify the styles i want, but it doesn't work either.

(Everything is inside the same file, which is content-container.html)

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `iron-media-query` instead of css `media-query` for styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to achieve this ([which is the one used in the `iron-media-query` demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-media-query/blob/master/demo/index.html)) is to use Polymer's [annotated attribute bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding) together with [attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute.asp).

A simple example of an element's template would look like this

```
<template>
<style>
  .content-wrapper ::content {
    color: blue;
  }

  .content-wrapper[mobile-layout] ::content {
    color: green;
  }
</style>

<iron-media-query query="(max-width:768px)" query-matches="{{isMobilePhone}}"></iron-media-query>
<div class="content-wrapper" mobile-layout$="[[isMobilePhone]]">
  <content></content>
</div>
</template>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ojubeoa/) showing it in action

Comment: Nice ! How could i modify the :host { } element this way ? I mean, there is no way to add the 'mobile-layout' attribute since there is no markup for the host element..

Comment: I think defining a property with the `reflectToAttribute` parameter and using it as the attribute selector should be enough ([here's a fiddle showing that](https://jsfiddle.net/89y26823/1/))

Comment: For some reason, i cant make it work. Could you please take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m206r1bj/) ?

Comment: you were missing a `}` after your property, your script had html mixed in it and it should be `:host[is-mobile-phone]` not `:host[mobile-layout]` (look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m206r1bj/1/))

Comment: @tony19 Thank you both. I'm gonna accept this answer since it might be more useful to others too, and its more 'Polymer' specific.

Answer (score 2):

`<style>` tags anywhere inside a `<dom-module>` (even `dom-if`) are applied to the element immediately (as seen in this [demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VjPzwQ?editors=1000)), so putting `<style>` inside a `dom-if` would not give you conditional styles.

And if the only purpose of using `<iron-media-query>` was to add a conditional `<style>`, you don't need the element at all. Just use the media query normally in CSS:

```
<style>
    ...

    #title {
        color: #7DB8C9;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

    @media (max-width:768px) {
        #title {
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 1.8em;
        }
    }
</style>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pbRrJv?editors=1000)

Comment: I see.. So whats the purpose of the iron-media-query ? Is it to add specific conditional markup ?

Comment: Right, you could use it to selectively add/remove elements based on a media query.

Comment: @DavidAzar I think you can't use css media queries in element's style

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to set custom properties or mixins [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045958/media-dont-work-properly-with-polymer-custom-css) [won't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783006/cant-style-element-in-shadow-dom-in-media-query) [work](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2149)

Comment: Yeah, that might be worth noting but probably not necessarily applicable to this question, which uses no CSS custom properties. Ignoring that limitation, media queries generally do work in the element's style.